Creating schema on ORACLE db using JPA buddy
Hi i'm trying to create my database schema and tables from JPA entities.
I am using an Oracle database.
When i execute the query i get this error:
[2024-05-16 18:32:02] [42000][1918] ORA-01918: user 'users' does not exist. 
[2024-05-16 18:32:02] Position: 0

The problem is that i want my "users" to be a SCHEMA instead of a USER and then insert into it the relative "user" table, making the schema and table's structure like " users.user".
This is an example of one of my Entities:
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER", schema = "USERS")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "USERID", nullable = false, length = 15)
    private String userid;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false, length = 40)
    private String username;

      ...

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

        ...
}

When i generate the DDL to execute I got an SQL like this:
CREATE TABLE users.user
(
    userid                     VARCHAR2(15)  NOT NULL,
    username                   VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
);

Is there a way to make it generating also the "CREATE SCHEMA" statement?

No, JPA Buddy cannot generate a new schema. We didn't even consider such feature, but I don't think we will implement that someday. Some reasons:

This is not so routine daily operation, that requires automation.
It usually requires special right access.
JPA Buddy uses Liquibase to make models comparison (even if required result is SQL), but Liquibase also doesn't contain a changeSet to create schemas.

